# How to have css transitions execute on scroll into viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a grid on this website I am working on that the background image expands on hover of each box. On mobile, I would like to have this same effect occur when each box on scrolled into the viewport. I found a nice library from jackonthe.net called CS3 Animate It. However, the effect occurs only when the page is refreshed/resized to mobile size and occurs on all boxes at the same time rather than one at a time on scroll.

```css
/* CSS Styles for the revised "Our Work" page */
    
    /* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
    
    .work__container--mobile {display: inline !important;}
    .work__container--other {display: none !important;}
    
    .work__container {
       height: auto;
       display: flex;
       background-color: #F1F1F1;
       flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .work__flex {
       width: 100vw;
       height: auto;
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
       justify-content: flex-start !important;
    }
    
    .work__flex--item {
       width: 100vw;
       height: 100vw;
       position: relative;
       overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .work_overlay {
       background-position: right bottom;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
    .work_overlay {
       background-size: 100% 100%;
       transition: 0.25s;
    }
    
    .work_overlay:hover {
       background-size: 107% 107%;
       transition: ease 0.25s;
    }
    
    .overlay__text {
       color: white !important;
       width: auto;
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 10px;
       margin-left: 25px;
    }
    
    .overlay__text--header {
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    .work__flex--item.hidden.item__arrow {
        display: flex !important;
        justify-content: center !important;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    
    .animate__arrow {
       animation:upArrow 2s infinite;
       -webkit-animation:upArrow 2s infinite;
    }
    
    .arrow {
       width: 30px !important;
       height: auto !important;
       margin: auto !important;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes upArrow { 
                0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0);} 
                40% {-webkit-transform: translateY(30px);} 
                60% {-webkit-transform: translateY(15px);} 
             } 
             
             @keyframes upArrow { 
                0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {transform: translateY(0);} 
                40% {transform: translateY(30px);} 
                60% {transform: translateY(15px);} 
             }
    
    .full {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
    .hidden {display: none;}
    .work__flex--item.hidden.item__arrow {display: none !important;}
    
    p.overlay__text--sub {
      font-size: 16px !important;
    }
    
    h2, .h2 {
       font-size: 40px !important;
       text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    .section-head p {
       font-size: 22px !important;
    }
    
    /* Mobile in landscape orientation */
    @media (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: landscape) {
       
    .work__container--mobile {display: none !important;}
    .work__container--other {display: inline !important;}
    
    .work__flex {
       flex-direction: row;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
       
    .work__flex--item {
       width: 50vw;
       height: 50vw;
    }
    
    .hidden {display: inline !important;}
    .duplicate {display: none !important;}
    
    .work__flex--item.hidden.item__arrow {
        display: flex !important;
        justify-content: center !important;
    }
        
    }
    
    /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
    
    .work__container--mobile {display: none !important;}
    .work__container--other {display: inline !important;}
    
    .work__flex {
       flex-direction: row;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
       
    .work__flex--item {
       width: 50vw;
       height: 50vw;
    }
    
    .hidden {display: inline !important;}
    .duplicate {display: none !important;}
    
    .work__flex--item.hidden.item__arrow {
        display: flex !important;
        justify-content: center !important;
    }
        
    }
    
    /* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
    
    .work__container--mobile {display: none !important;}
    .work__container--other {display: inline !important;}
    
    .work__flex {
       flex-direction: row;
    }
    
    .work__flex--item {
       width: 33.33vw;
       height: 33.33vw;
    }
    
    .hidden {display: none !important;}
    .duplicate {display: inline !important;}
    .work__flex--item.hidden.item__arrow {display: none !important;}
    
    }
    
    /* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    
    .work__container--mobile {display: none !important;}
    .work__container--other {display: inline !important;}
    
    }
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animations.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <script src="js/css3-animate-it.js"></script>
    
         <div class="work__container work__container--mobile">
        <div class="work__flex">
            <div class="work__flex--item animatedParent">
                <div class="full work_overlay animated pulse animate-this">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="work__flex--item hidden item__arrow">
                <div class="arrow animate__arrow">
                    <a href="#services-wrap" class="smooth-scroll">
                                             
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
<script>
    
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var windowSize = $(window).outerWidth();

    if ( windowSize <= 768 ) {

        $(window).on("scroll", function() {

            $(".animate-this").each(function() {

                var documentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                var documentBottom = documentTop + $(window).height();
                var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
                var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).height();

                if ( (elementTop >= documentTop) && (elementBottom <= documentBottom) ) {

                    $(this).addClass("my-animation");
                    $(this).removeClass("animate-this");

                }

            });

        });

    }

});

</script>
```

Comment: You should read this article http://xtianmiller.com/notes/animating-elements-when-they-appear-in-viewport/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. Add a class to each element you want to animate when it's scrolled into the viewport so the JS knows which elements to animate.

For example add `.animate-this` to locate the elements to animate. Then when it's scrolled into view it will add the animation class and remove the `animate-this` class to stop it from looping constantly. `.my-animation` will be the class that has the animation on it.

Requires jQuery but lightweight.

***Edit***

Updated the code. This should only be ran when on a mobile device (ie. small screen) and work if the page is resized multiple times.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var windowSize = $(window).outerWidth();

    if ( windowSize <= 768 ) {

        $(window).on("scroll", function() {

            $(".animate-this").each(function() {

                var documentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                var documentBottom = documentTop + $(window).height();
                var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
                var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).height();

                if ( (elementTop >= documentTop) && (elementBottom <= documentBottom) ) {

                    $(this).addClass("my-animation");

                } else {

                    $(this).removeClass("my-animation");

                }

            });

        });

    }

});
```

Comment: Can I just include that script inline?

Comment: The footer is the best place but yes, you could if you wanted. Just include the script tags around it. I'll update it to include the document ready line as well because you'll need that.

Comment: Not sure if I implemented it properly but it still has the same effect where it only does the transition on refresh. I'll update the question if you want to take a look

Comment: So it works on mobile but requires a refresh for it to work? I'll update the answer.

Comment: I want it to not require the refresh and only animate the box when it enters the viewport. However, right now it still animates all of them at the same time and only on refresh.

Comment: Okay try that, hopefully that does what you're after.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138649/discussion-between-spencer-m-and-daniel-james).

Comment: one last question, how would I be able to make the effect execute more than once? (the box is scrolled into the viewport more than once without refreshing)

Comment: Added an else into the if statement which should sort this.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar issue with triggering css animations once elements were either first scrolled into view or at some other specific point on the screen. I ended up using Waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/), they have both a version that plays nicely with jQuery and also a vanilla JS version.

With this, you can set a waypoint corresponding to each of the elements you want to animate (Or even create them through a loop if your classes/ids are numerated E.G: id1, id2...), set the point on the screen you want the callback function to trigger, then put any css manipulations inside the callback.

For a reference, here's the code I used with the jQuery framework:

```
$('.pie').each(function() {
        $(this).waypoint(function() {
            const id = $(this.element).attr('id');
            if (state[id]) {
                return;
            }
            state[id] = true;
            animateSlice(id);
        }, {
            offset: 'bottom-in-view'
        })
    })
```